# Two dimensions data, display no results

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner with angularJs

I have json data on two dimensions :

```
[
    {
        "nom": "Name 1",
        "subventions": [
            {
                "beneficiaire": "ben\u00e9f Phipippe C mars 2015",
                "montant": "7<span class='space'><\/span>898,99",
                "annee": 1,
                "trimestre": 4,
                "infoAdditionnelle": "<p>info mars - 2015<\/p>\r\n<div id=\"nested_deluminate_fullscreen_workaround\" style=\"background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\">\u00a0<\/div>"
            },
            {
                "beneficiaire": "cvbcvbn",
                "projet": "<p>cvnnncbcnbcbn<\/p>",
                "circonscription": "456sdxfvxc",
                "montant": "131,00",
                "annee": 3,
                "trimestre": 2,
                "infoAdditionnelle": "<p>test<\/p>"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "nom": "Name 2",
        "subventions": [
            {
                "beneficiaire": "pierre m",
                "montant": "1<span class='space'><\/span>000,00",
                "annee": 3,
                "trimestre": 1,
                "infoAdditionnelle": "<p>avtil 2015-16<\/p>"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "nom": "Name 3",
        "subventions": [
            {
                "beneficiaire": "bene pierre p avril 2015-16",
                "montant": "1<span class='space'><\/span>222,00",
                "annee": 3,
                "trimestre": 1,
                "infoAdditionnelle": "<p>p avril 2015-16<\/p>"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, there is an array of persons containing the field "nom" and "subventions", "subventions is also an array

I have filters by the fields "annee" and "trimestre", and what i want to do is when there's not result to display, to display a "no results" message

To calculate the number of results, i use this function

```
$scope.filterArray = function(resultsPersonnes) {
    var data = resultsPersonnes.filter(function(prop) {
        return prop.subventions[0].annee == $scope.annee.id;
    });
    if ($scope.myFilter.trimestre > 0) {
        return data.filter(function(prop) {
            return prop.subventions[0].trimestre == $scope.myFilter.trimestre;
        });
    } else {
        return data
    }

}
```

It's doesn't work for all the cases, you can see an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/9TbO0Hl9LziUS2B6AsAr?p=preview

If you click on "Juillet - septembre" in "Trimestre, i got one result, but the "no results" message is displayed!!!

do you see the error ? please help!

Thanks a lot

Comment: because filterArray(resultsPersonnes).length is really 0

Comment: I think it's because of the [0] as it's always checking the first row. But how ti fix it ? what should i put instead ? I'm lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already guessed in your comment, you were checking only the first row. The fix is to check all rows, for example like this, using `Array.some` (which returns true if at least one item in array returns true for the function given as parameter)

*Edit: the filtering needs to be updated into a single filter*

```
$scope.filterArray = function(resultsPersonnes) {
    var data = resultsPersonnes.filter(function(prop) {
      return prop.subventions.some(function (subvention) {
        var anneeMatches = subvention.annee == $scope.annee.id;
        var trimestreMatches = true;
        if ($scope.myFilter.trimestre > 0) {
          trimestreMatches = subvention.trimestre == $scope.myFilter.trimestre;
        }
        return anneeMatches && trimestreMatches;
      });
    });
    return data;
};
```

[**See working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/B902qTUjgQy9IzusJTSw?p=preview)

Comment: The only problem i see, is that when i change the dropdown value to 2014-2015, and i click on "Juillet - septembre", there are no results, but the "no results" message is not displayed :(

Comment: Ah, very true, my bad for missing that. In this case you just need to do the filtering once, see my edited answer.